# React Leaflet - get Tiles Offline

Tags: javascript, leaflet, react-leaflet

I use [leaflet.offline](https://github.com/allartk/leaflet.offline) which allows to save the tiles in indexedDB.
The backup is done by a click on a button 'L.control'.
I would like this backup to be automatic each time you start a map (without button).
How to do it with leaflet.offline or do you know another way, please?

Layer creation - works fine

```js
const tileLayerOffline = L.tileLayer.offline(
  "https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
  {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
    subdomains: "abc",
    crossOrigin: true,
    minZoom: 13,
    maxZoom: 16,
  }
)
```

Launch button

```js
const controlSaveTiles = L.control.savetiles(tileLayerOffline, {
  zoomlevels: [13, 16], // optional zoomlevels to save, default current zoomlevel
});
controlSaveTiles.addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the source code, the `savetiles` control button triggers the `_saveTiles()` method. You can call this method directly on the `controlSaveTiles` variable which contains a reference to the `savetiles` control.

```
const controlSaveTiles = L.control.savetiles(tileLayerOffline, {
  zoomlevels: [13, 16]
});
controlSaveTiles._saveTiles(); // no need to addTo(map), just save
```

Code that creates the control buttons:
https://github.com/allartk/leaflet.offline/blob/master/src/ControlSaveTiles.js#L123

Method that saves the tiles:
https://github.com/allartk/leaflet.offline/blob/master/src/ControlSaveTiles.js#L144

Comment: thanks, i see the method but I can't access to _saveTiles(),  do you know another way ?